# Pygame Window is black

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a simple mandelbrot renderer. After the program calculates and draws everything, it saves the surface and blits it. This worked fine, but after I added the update display function, it only shows a black screen. I will need to update every iteration because I will add some text and other things. I only included the important parts of the program. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
def keys(): #Recognises key-presses
    global x
    global y
    global zoom
    global mdb
    global z
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: y += 1/z
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: y -= 1/z
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: x -= 1/z
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: x += 1/z
    if pressed[pygame.K_i]: zoom+=1
    if pressed[pygame.K_o]: zoom-=1
    if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        z=z*zoom
        mdbprint(mandelbrot(x*z-width/2, y*-1*z-height/2, z))
        mdb=pygame.Surface((width,height))
        zoom=1


def draw_variables():
    global mdb
    w.blit(mdb, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------



mdbprint(mandelbrot(x-width/2,y-height/2,z))
mdb=pygame.Surface((width,height))


print(time.perf_counter())
while True:
    keys()
    draw_variables()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to pass the `mdb` surface to `mdbprint()`, but it is a global and it is what you blit onto `w`, so I assume that is what `mdbprint()` draws on (otherwise it is not clear what mdb is for. However you always seem to have these two lines in this order:

```
    mdbprint(mandelbrot(x*z-width/2, y*-1*z-height/2, z))
    mdb=pygame.Surface((width,height))
```

Which means that after you draw to `mdb` you them overwrite the variable with a brand new surface and throw the old one away. That new surface will of course be empty.

By the way, you normally just clear a Surface by `fill()`ing it, not by starting over with a new Surface.